# Unable to connect to data source. Reason: Unable to locate database server

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008, ssas

I am trying to use Excel 2007 to connect to my 2008 Analysis Server (64 bit SQL 2008 on Small Business Server 2008).

From Excel, I go:
Data --> From Other Sources --> From Analysis Services

Then I get an error message: Unable to connect to data source. Reason: Unable to locate database server.

Should this functionality work out of the box? Or do I need to install an add-in or something?

thanks

Comment: I just experienced this as well, even with existing connections that once worked.